# Lightbox title caption not working

Tags: html, css, lightbox, title, caption

I'm a real novice and trying to use a web template to design my own website.

I have a basic lightbox gallery and it all works ok, but whatever I have tried, I cannot get a caption to show on the gallery image (not the thumbnail image).

This is a snippet of the html code with a single gallery item:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="image">
   <div class="overlay">
    <a href="img/gallery/gallery-item1.jpg" data-rel="lightbox" data-title="explanation of image goes in here"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="img/gallery/gallery-item1.jpg" alt="image 4">
   </div>
```

I've tried using title="caption" instead of data-title ="caption", but no joy. Here is the css for the lightbox:

```
#lightbox {
cursor: pointer;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: black;
/* IE Fallback (Solid Colour) */
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAIElEQVQ4T2NkYGDYDMRkA8ZRAxhGw4BhNAyA+WAYpAMAIFgLQfO9BoEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
-webkit-filter: none !important;
}

#lightbox img {
display: block;
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
border-radius: 1px;
}

body.blurred > * {
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.lightbox-loading {
background: url(../img/loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
width: 31px;
height: 31px;
margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
position: absolute;
top: 48%;
left: 50%;
}  

.lightbox-caption {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1000;
background: #000;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.lightbox-caption p {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 70%;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
}

.lightbox-button {
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
background: no-repeat center center;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
opacity: 0.4;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.lightbox-button:hover,
.lightbox-button:focus {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
-moz-transform: scale(1.4);
-ms-transform: scale(1.4);
transform: scale(1.4);
}

.lightbox-close {
right: 30px;
top: 30px;
background-image: url("../img/close.png");
}

.lightbox-next {
right: 30px;
top: 48%;
background-image: url("../img/next.png");
}

.lightbox-previous {
left: 30px;
top: 48%;
background-image: url("../img/previous.png");
}
```

any tips / help is welcomed. thanks

Comment: Which lightbox script you use?

Comment: Can you link to a site, or a demo with the lighbox plugin? It's difficult to see what's going wrong without it

Comment: @ovokuro

thanks for the replies. I took the lightbox from a free web template because I liked the lightbox only. I've uploaded a test page with the basic lightbox and css and js files:

    http://sugastore.com/test/gallery-temp.html

Here is the original web template, though I've simply taken the elements I need from it to put into my site (so it's the same js and css) but here's the link anyway:

    http://www.templatemo.com/tm-397-concept

Comment: @sinisake - I'm not sure which lightbox, jquery lightbox and bootstrap? I've provided the link here: http://sugastore.com/test/gallery-temp.html

Answer (score 1):

The caption is being loaded by the 'data-caption' attribute in your anchor tag.

Your anchor tags currently look like this:

```
<a href="img/gallery/gallery-item1.jpg" data-rel="lightbox" class="fa fa-expand"></a>
```

You need to insert the caption like this:

```
<a href="images/gallery/gallery-item1.jpg" data-caption="caption here" data-rel="lightbox" class="fa fa-expand"></a>
```

For your own interest, if you look at the javascript in the source files you'll see these lines:

```
setCaption: function () {
                var caption = $(plugin.current).data('caption');
                if(!!caption && caption.length > 0) {
                    plugin.caption.fadeIn();
                    $('p', plugin.caption).text(caption);
                }else{
                    plugin.caption.hide();
                }
            },
```

The second line says:

```
var caption = $(plugin.current).data('caption');
```

This is setting the caption to whatever text you have in the `data-caption` field. If it said `.data('title')`, then you would use `data-title = "my caption"`

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank-you so much for spending the time to reply and with this information - it worked!! the caption now shows on the main large lightbox image. 
I spend ages trying to figure this out but with no result, so thank-you for so much for helping on this and also for the tip on where to find the corresponding js - it helps me in learning this stuff. Kindly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Need more code to check I would say but you do have

```
.lightbox-caption {
display: none;
}
```

This would usually hide this class.  Maybe try and remove display:none or change to block or inline etc?

Comment: thanks - I adjusted the css to block and inline and now the caption shows but not on the pop-up image. When I put the:

     <div class='lightbox-caption'>Your caption here</div>

into the page - I can only get the caption to display on the thumbnail or the thumbnail overlay - not the actual lightbox image that pops up.

The link: http://sugastore.com/test/gallery-temp.html